# is there any toy similarity matrix to test my random walk code?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix

I am looking for a toy similarity matrix of any kind of entity class to test my random walk code. Is there any set like this or how can I create my own set? I need to interpret the results of the random walk that I run to find the dominant instances of the data.

Comment: Any distance matrix or correlation matrix should work.

Comment: But I need to know the data to get a meaning out of the results of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a toy matrix?

Just get some small (maybe toy) data set, and compute the similarity matrix for it, and verify it against the original data.